# Missing theme after switching to from HTML to Freemarker

Tags: html, freemarker

I am relatively new to freemarker and I am trying to convert a **.html file**, that displays correctly, to a **.ftl file**.

The conversion of the main part of the web page went great (all the elements are there), except for the **theme** (background) of the web page. It doesn't display, but it was in the html.

My theme is just a link that points to a .min.css file.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/themes-dist-4.0.27-theme-gcwu-fegc/theme-gcwu-fegc/css/theme.min.css">
```

I am trying to understand if you can pass "html to ftl" straight? 
Also, can you display a theme in a ftl file?

EDIT:
The answer to this was to put the file into a public directory (ressources/public/themes/*). The compiler picked it up from there.

Comment: If you rename a html file to ftl file, it will work as is as long as your backend is setup correctly. For your theme file, that sounds like css. Add some code on how the theme is supposed to be included

Comment: Yeah I think my backend has been setup correctly. I have done the straight conversion before. Should I include the full css ? @Huangism

Comment: No, the problem is most likely not the css itself since it worked before. 1 - does your other css files work? 2 - are you certain the theme css is on the page and the url to the file is correct? 3 - use inspector to see if something is getting overridden in css

Comment: Yes my other css file work­. Yes the url to the file is correct. And no it is not overriden in css. It is the only imported css file in this ftl file.

Comment: Do you see the content of the css file? if it is not overridden then it should work (i am assuming you see the content of the file which is how you know it is not overridden)

Comment: Yes that is what I will do. Investigate if the Css file has been overriden. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You might need to understand that FreeMarker template files are executed on the server, and the browser just sees the output as regular HTLM. Thus, you can simply rename a `.html` to `.ftl` (or rather to `.ftlh`), and since it contains no FreeMarker directives, that template simply prints the original HTML as is.

Check on the developer panel (usually opens with F12) of your browser if the CSS file was successfully loaded. The CSS file is (usually) not a FreeMarker template, just a "static" file, so it's unrelated to FreeMarker (though of course it can also be generated by FreeMarker if you need dynamism there).

Comment: Yes thank you for the explanation. I will look into if the css file has been overriden or not.